# Systemd ignores notify PID when similar service is running

Tags: systemd, process, minecraft

I have two services that are almost identical, except for the paths. Each service runs a Minecraft server on tmux. Here's the generic unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=<description>
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
ExecStart=<Path to start script>
ExecStop=<path to stop script>
WorkingDirectory=<path to dir>
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=120
User=<user>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SESSION_NAME=<name>
SERVER_JAR=<jar path>
MEMORY=<ram>

tmux new-session -d -s ${SESSION_NAME} 'java -Xms'"${MEMORY}"' -Xmx'"${MEMORY}"' -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs -Daikars.new.flags=true -Dpaper.playerconnection.keepalive=120 -Dsession_name='"${SESSION_NAME}"' -jar '"${SERVER_JAR}"' nogui'

main_pid=$(pgrep -a java | awk '/session_name='"${SESSION_NAME}"'/ {print $1}')
echo ${main_pid}

systemd-notify --ready --pid=${main_pid}
```

stop script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
  
SESSION_NAME=<name>

# 10 second warning
echo "10 Second warning"
tmux send-keys -t ${SESSION_NAME} 'say "Server shutting down in 10 seconds"' ENTER

sleep 10 # wait 10 seconds

# Stop server
echo "Stopping server..."
tmux send-keys -t ${SESSION_NAME} 'stop' ENTER

# Wait for screen to terminate
while tmux ls | grep -q ${SESSION_NAME}
do
        sleep 1
done
echo "Server stopped"
```

I have two services set up in the exact same way, with different names and paths. Starting the first server works fine, and it receives the proper PID. However, when I start the second service it immediately exits and runs the stop script. Systemd seems to be ignoring the PID of the second process, even though it receives the notify message (I can set a status through systemd-notify). There is only a problem when one service is already running, and it doesn't matter which order I start them in, the second one always fails in this way.

I'd like to know why this happens, and how to work around it. I'd rather keep using start/stop scripts as it is easier to manage and set up new servers, and it avoids some headache with selinux when creating a new server.

My system is Rocky Linux 8.5, running systemd 250

Comment: Did you check the service's log to see whether the service has decided to stop running by itself? For example, because the first service has already bound port 25565?

Comment: @user253751 No issue if I run the server manually using the scripts. Systemd is specifically running the stop script immediately after the start script exits, ignoring the new PID.